# How to encode values in DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark(2.x) DataFrame with the following columns:

```
nodes_df.show()

------|------
node  | group
------|------
AAA   | 1
BBB   | 1
CCC   | 2
```

Performing the following operation on the `nodes_df` dataframe, row numbers are added.

```
val nodes = nodes_df
  .withColumn("id",row_number().over(Window.orderBy("group")))
nodes.show()

node  | group
------|------
1     | 1
2     | 1
3     | 2
```

I have another dataframe, `arcs_df`

```
arcs_df.show()

node_from  | node_to | weight
-----------|---------|-------
AAA        | BBB     | 1
BBB        | CCC     | 1
```

I would like to know, using encoding, how to assign the corresponding node numbers in `nodes` to the `node_from` and `node_to` column values in `arcs_df`.

I want to get a dataframe that looks like the following

```
final_df.show()

node_from  | node_to | weight
-----------|---------|-------
1          | 2       | 1
2          | 3       | 1
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to encode string values into numeric values in Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48082451/how-to-encode-string-values-into-numeric-values-in-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that below doesn't use encoding but it does exactly what you want using joins. Lets walk through it together.

**Necessary imports**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
```

**Create nodes_df**

```
val data1 = Seq(("AAA",1), ("BBB",1), ("CCC",2))
val nodes_df = data1.toDF("node", "group")
nodes_df.show()

+----+-----+
|node|group|
+----+-----+
| AAA|    1|
| BBB|    1|
| CCC|    2|
+----+-----+
```

**Create nodes**

Use `row_number` and `Window` to add row number. I changed the orderBy from `group` to `node` because you have no guarantee if AAA will be 1 and BBB will be 2 or vice versa since they have the same `group` number.

```
val nodes = nodes_df.withColumn("id",row_number().over(Window.orderBy("node")))
nodes.show()

+----+-----+---+
|node|group| id|
+----+-----+---+
| AAA|    1|  1|
| BBB|    1|  2|
| CCC|    2|  3|
+----+-----+---+
```

**Create arcs_df**

```
val data2 = Seq(("AAA","BBB",1), ("BBB","CCC",1))
val arcs_df = data2.toDF("node_from", "node_to", "weight")
arcs_df.show()

+---------+-------+------+
|node_from|node_to|weight|
+---------+-------+------+
|      AAA|    BBB|     1|
|      BBB|    CCC|     1|
+---------+-------+------+
```

**Perform joins to get your desired output**

Now we are essentially where you wanted to know how to map the `id` from `nodes` to from/to nodes in `arcs_df`. I accomplished that by using two joins. First is from `nodes` to `arcs_df`, creating an intermediate dataframe, `first_join_df`, for illustrative purposes. Then from `nodes` to `first_join_df`. After the joins I drop columns that I don't care about, like `group`, and rename the `id` column to `node_from`/`node_to` where applicable. I finish with a `.select(...` to get the order that you asked for. Take a look and let me know if anything isn't clear. Hope this helps!

```
val first_join_df = arcs_df.join(nodes, arcs_df.col("node_from") === nodes.col("node"), "leftouter")
  .drop("node_from", "node", "group")
  .withColumnRenamed("id", "node_from")
first_join_df.show()

+-------+------+---------+
|node_to|weight|node_from|
+-------+------+---------+
|    BBB|     1|        1|
|    CCC|     1|        2|
+-------+------+---------+

val second_join_df = first_join_df.join(nodes, first_join_df.col("node_to") === nodes.col("node"), "leftouter")
  .drop("node_to", "node", "group")
  .withColumnRenamed("id", "node_to")
  .select("node_from", "node_to", "weight")
second_join_df.show()

+---------+-------+------+
|node_from|node_to|weight|
+---------+-------+------+
|        1|      2|     1|
|        2|      3|     1|
+---------+-------+------+
```